# Sklearn PCA decomposition explained_variance_ratio_

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am a python rookie, these days I was learning PCA decomposition, when I use the explained_variance_ratio_ I found that the results are sorted by default by default like these:

`Ratio: [9.99067005e-01 8.40367350e-04 4.97276068e-05 2.46358647e-05
 1.00120681e-05 8.25213366e-06]`

This is my previous operation：

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
my_pca = PCA(n_components=7)
new_df = df.drop(labels=["salary","department","left"],axis=1)
low_mat = my_pca.fit_transform(new_df)
print("Ratio:",my_pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

I was so confused which was the most important components, so I want to know do you have some ways to let the composition and ratio one-to-one correspondence, like this:

```
Ratio: satisfaction_level 9.99067005e-01
......
```

thank you!

Comment: What is `satisfaction_level`?

Comment: Just one of the components @giser_yugang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned what is `satisfaction_level`, I assume its a feature in your data set. Also I assume that you are expecting feature wise variance values.

[PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) has parameter called `n_components` which indicates the number of components you want to keep in a transferred space. PCA is used for dimensionality reduction.So `n_components` has to be less than number of features you have.

PCA will do dimensionality reduction by rotating the features to get the maximum variance. Each feature in PCA will be orthogonal to each other. So you will not be able to see the same features values as you see in your original data set.

The features in PCA will be transformed to get high variance. Higher the variance, higher the percentage of information is retained.

`explained_variance_ratio_` is the percentage of variance explained by each of the selected components. First component will be having having higher variance & last component will be having least variance. The percentage values are sorted in decreasing order

So if you want to get the transformed features (the most important features), do this

```
pca_features = my_pca.components_
```

You can make a dataframe out of it as well.

> P.S: Before applying PCA, make sure that you have standardised the input data

Comment: Firstly,Thank you Kalsi. satisfaction_level is just one of the components, I will try it after work,Thanks again：）

Comment: I understand my mistake, explained_variance_ratio_not match the original feature, but the principal component direction that is found by the algorithm(explained_variance_).